# showing Content upon hovering on video

Tags: html, css, html5-video

i want to show some Content in class "overlay header" upon hovering the video like controls .
like video name and other elements.

when i set hover property on video. it doesn't reflect.

and i want to make a provision that after hovering the content in overlay header displays and disappears after 5 seconds.
can somebody help me with the css.
here is my html code

```
<body>
  <div class="video-container">
    <div class="overlay-header"><h1>Joker</h1></div>
    <div class="video-wrapper">
      <video class="video" autoplay controls>
        <source src="../../assets/movies/joker.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

here is my css code

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
}

video {
  background-color: black;
  outline: none;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.video-container video {
  z-index: 0;
}
.overlay-header {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have the title visible for only 5 seconds you will need to add JS of some form to add the timing function.

However, to get the title on hover I have added the css in a codepen: 
https://codepen.io/adamjamesturner/pen/PowMLve

HTML

```
<body>
  <div class="video-container">
    <div class="video-wrapper">
      <video class="video" autoplay controls>
        <source src="../../assets/movies/joker.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
      </video>
      <div class="overlay-header"><h1>Joker</h1></div> // By moving to here I can use the sibling selector in CSS
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
}

video {
  background-color: black;
  outline: none;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.video-container video {
  z-index: 0;
}
.overlay-header {
  display: none;    // HIDE THE TITLE UNTIL HOVER
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.video:hover + .overlay-header { ON VIDEO HOVER, DISPLAY THE SIBLING TITLE COMPONENT
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: can i do it using angular?

Comment: the time functionality after hover

Comment: You can definitely use Angular to do this.

Comment: The changes below should get you in the right direction

In the class component: 
Create a variable `headerVisible = false`.  
Create a function: 
public changeTitleVisible() {
   this.titleVisible = true;
   setTimeout(() => {this.titleVisible = false}, 5000)
}

In the template:
<video class="video" (mouseover)="changeTitleVisible($event)" autoplay controls>
<div [class.overlay-header-visible]="titleVisible"><h1>Joker</h1></div>

change CSS:
.overlay-header-visible { 
  display: block;
}

Comment: thanks .. can you help me make a seek bar using angular..can we communicate?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in Jquery like so

```
$(".overlay-header").hide();
$(".video").hover( function(){
$(".overlay-header").show();
setTimeout(function(){
$(".overlay-header").hide();
}, 5000);
})
```